# Excel max number in range

Tags: excel

I have a column A with many numbers (that are from 2000000 to 4999999). 
In cell K3 I want to have the maximum number of this column in the range of 280030 and 289999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D1011 is my min value and E1012 is my max value

```
=MAX(WENN((B4:B999>D1011)*(B4:B999<E1012);B4:B999))
```

That works!

Answer (score 1):

### ASSUMPTION:

Assuming the set of numbers is between 2,000,000 to 4,999,999 & the conditional Max needs to return the highest number between 2,800,300 and 2,899,999 ( Instead of 280,030 and 289,999 )

### EXCEL WITH HELPER COLUMN ( NOT ARRAY ):

1. If you are using excel you can use a helper column to convert all numbers of the larger set to zero that do not conform to the criteria of being between 2,800,300 and 2,899,999. I accomplished this with a formula and copied it down `=IF(AND(A1>2800300,A1<2899999),A1,)` such that the helper column has an output for every number in Column A.
2. If my helper column is in Column B, you can use the max formula `=MAX(B:B)` to return the conditional max.

### GOOGLE SHEETS WITH ARRAY ( NOT HELPER COLUMN ):

- Simply use the filter array to remove all cells of column A that are less than 2,800,300 or greater than 2,899,999, and take the max: `=MAX(FILTER(A:A,A:A>2800300,A:A<2899999))`

Comment: I didn't see that before. That said The criteria is out of range. If I have a set of numbers between 2,000,000 & 4,999,999 I will never find a subset of numbers between 280,030 & 289,999. If there is no subset, I can't find a max of an empty set.

Comment: I just fixed it -- Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: What error do you encounter? Are you using excel,  or google?

Comment: I use Excel.
First of all I had to type ; instead of , So the formula looks like      =IF(AND(A1>2800300;A1<2899999);A1;) Then there is the following error: The formula contains text that cannot be interpreted.

Comment: Then use [a translation like this](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/?page=deutsch-english.html) so you can utilize formulas you see on this forum. For instance, there is no "IF" formula in Deutsch Excel. I attempted to translate & use semicolons instead of commas: `=WENN(UND(A1>2800300;A1<2899999);A1;FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as it is an array formula.

```
=MAX(IF(A:A>=280030,IF(A:A<=289999,A:A)))
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Error? Can give the error message. It is a tested formula. Do you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering formula?

Comment: First of all I had to type ; instead of , So the formula looks like     =MAX(IF(A:A>=280030;IF(A:A<=289999;A:A)))
Then there is the following error: The formula contains text that cannot be interpreted.

Comment: Why you have to type ; (Semicolon) instead , (Comma). I putted screenshot from excel. You have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when you finish typing formula.